# Cerrar Sesión Automaticamente en Json Web Tokkens Node Js

Tags: nodejs, jwt

Muy Buenos dias Comunidad recurro a ustedes para que me puedan ayudar con Las sesiones JWT en Node.js
actualmente este es mi codigo

```
let verificaToken = (req, res, next) => {

    let token = req.cookies.token;

    jwt.verify(token,process.env.SEED, (err, decoded) => {

        if (err) {
            res.redirect("/");
            return
        }

        req.usuario = decoded.usuario;
        next();

    });

};
```

y si cierra sesion pero no me lo redirecciona cuando caduca el tiempo del Jwt que esta en 1 hora (60*60)
en mis api's lo utlizo así

```
app.get("/busqueda-proveedor/:nombre", [verificaToken, verificaAdmin_Role], (req, res) => {

    let nombre = req.params.nombre;

    consultaSQL(`SELECT * FROM proveedores WHERE nombre LIKE '%${nombre}%'`)
    .then(result => {

        if (result.length <= 0) {

            return res.json({
                ok: false,
                mensaje: "Lo sentimos no se ha encontrado ningun proveedor"
            })

        }

        res.json({
            ok: true,
            data: result
        })


    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
})
```

cuando la Sesión caduca y se hace una busqueda manda errores en la consola y tengo que refrescar la pagina para que recien me mande al login

adjunto tambien cuando consumo la api de mis servicios y alli donde me arroja el error 
(Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0)

```
function busquedaProveedor(nombre) {

    fetch(`${window.ruta}/busqueda-proveedor/${nombre}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {

        if (data.ok != false) {

            $('#ordenesProveedor').dataTable().fnDestroy();

            $('#ordenesProveedor').DataTable({
                'ajax': `${window.ruta}/busqueda-proveedor/${nombre}`,
                "processing": true,
                "bLengthChange" : false,
                "searching": false,
                "ordering": false,
                'columns': [

                    { "data": "nombre" },
                    { "data": "numerodocumento" },
                    {
                        "render": function (data, type, row) {
                            return `<button data-hint="Ver datos proveedor" class="btn btnProgramarGuias btn-warning hint--left" codProveedor="${row.codigo}" ><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></button>`;
                        }
                    }

                ], 
                'language': {
                    "url": "https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.16/i18n/Spanish.json"
                },

            });

        }else{

            swal({
                title: data.mensaje,
                type: 'error',
                confirmButtonText: 'Cerrar',
                confirmButtonColor: '#6b1180'
            }).then((result) => {

                if (result.value) {

                    $(".nombreProveedor").val("");
                    $(".nombreProveedor").focus();

                }

            })

        }

    })

}
```

Comment: ¿Porque haces un `return` después del `res.redirect(...)`? Usualmente debes hacerlo así: `return res.redirect(...);`. En la misma línea. Verifica eso y comenta los resultados. Saludos

Comment: no me funciona con lo que me dices estimado , se queda en la parte de la pagina y cuando busco un usuario me sigue saliendo el error en la consola ,

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar los errores que te da en la consola?. Además, se necesita ver la forma en la que capturas la respuesta de tu API en el lado frontend. Pulsa en [edit] y agrega lo que haga falta. Saludos

Comment: proveedores:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0  ese es el error que me devuelve y me señala en mi frontend que ahora lo acabo de modificar

Comment: Claro, el problema está en tu frontend. Fíjate que estás intentando hacer: `res => res.json()`, pero el servidor te ha redirigido a otra página y los datos que envía no son en formato JSON. El response que estás recibiendo empieza con `<!doctype...` y pues el método `res.json()` falla indicando el primer carácter `<` no válido. Debes capturar el caso en que has sido redirigido antes de intentar usar el `res => res.json()`. Saludos

Comment: Solucione mi Error , en el Frontend solo era agregarle un catch que capture el error .then,.then, .catch (modificare mi codigo para otras personas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como te expliqué en mi comentario, el problema está en la forma que manejas la respuesta del servidor.

Dado que estás usando la API [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), puedes usar algunas de sus propiedades para capturar la re dirección (en caso de que la hubiese).

La API `fetch` define o expone 2 objetos que representan el proceso de comunicación Cliente/Servidor mediante [`HTTP`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP). Estos objetos son Petición (o Solicitud)  y Respuesta ([`Request`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Request) y [`Response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Response)).

En tu caso particular, puedes usar una propiedad del Objeto `Response` llamada `redirected`. Como puedes suponer, esta propiedad estará establecida a `true` si la respuesta del servidor ha sido una re dirección a tu solicitud, y será `false` en caso contrario.

Una forma en la que podrías hacer el trabajo sería la siguiente:

```
function busquedaProveedor(nombre) {
  fetch(`${window.ruta}/busqueda-proveedor/${nombre}`)
    .then((res) => {
      if(res.redirected) { // <- verificamos si la respuesta es una re direccion
        return location.replace(res.url); // <- redirigimos la página
      } else {
        return res.json();
      }
    })
    .then(data => {
      if (data.ok) { // <- Si data.ok es true o false, no necesitas hacer data.ok != false
        $('#ordenesProveedor').dataTable().fnDestroy();
        $('#ordenesProveedor').DataTable(
          {
            'ajax': `${window.ruta}/busqueda-proveedor/${nombre}`,
            "processing": true,
            "bLengthChange" : false,
            "searching": false,
            "ordering": false,
            'columns': [
              { "data": "nombre" },
              { "data": "numerodocumento" },
              {
                "render": function (data, type, row) {
                  return `<button data-hint="Ver datos proveedor" class="btn btnProgramarGuias btn-warning hint--left" codProveedor="${row.codigo}" ><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></button>`;
                }
              }
            ], 
            'language': {
              "url": "https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.16/i18n/Spanish.json"
            },
          });
      } else {
        swal({
          title: data.mensaje,
          type: 'error',
          confirmButtonText: 'Cerrar',
          confirmButtonColor: '#6b1180'
        });
    .then((result) => {
      if (result.value) {
        $(".nombreProveedor").val("");
        $(".nombreProveedor").focus();
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(`Error: ${err.message}`);
      alert(err.message); // <-- Aquí pones algo acorde a lo que necesites
    });
  }
```

La forma en que captures el error o como proceses la re dirección variará de acuerdo a las especificaciones y requerimientos de tu aplicación.

No es mala práctica capturar el error, al contrario es muy buena práctica hacerlo.

Te llamará la atención que para hacer el `redirect` no utilicé `window.location`, en cambio usé el método `replace()` de `location`.

Puedes leer la documentación de [`location.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace). Lo hago así porque estamos hablando de sesiones, y dado que la re dirección se efectúa por causa de pérdida de credenciales (Token caducado), el método `location.replace()` elimina del historial del navegador la página actual. De esta forma el usuario al hacer `clic` en el botón `regresar` no podrá acceder a la página desde la que fue re dirigido.

Espero que esto aclare tus dudas.

Comment: Es lo correcto Mauricio Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 2):

Tuve que agregar un catch para capturar el error y redirigir a mi formulario de logeo,
si ha alguien se le ocurre una mejor , por favor publicarla a mi parecer esto no es de buenas practicas

```
function busquedaProveedor(nombre) {

    fetch(`${window.ruta}/busqueda-proveedor/${nombre}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {

        if (data.ok != false) {

            $('#ordenesProveedor').dataTable().fnDestroy();

            $('#ordenesProveedor').DataTable({
                'ajax': `${window.ruta}/busqueda-proveedor/${nombre}`,
                "processing": true,
                "bLengthChange" : false,
                "searching": false,
                "ordering": false,
                'columns': [

                    { "data": "nombre" },
                    { "data": "numerodocumento" },
                    {
                        "render": function (data, type, row) {
                            return `<button data-hint="Ver datos proveedor" class="btn btnProgramarGuias btn-warning hint--left" codProveedor="${row.codigo}" ><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></button>`;
                        }
                    }

                ], 
                'language': {
                    "url": "https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.16/i18n/Spanish.json"
                },

            });

        }else{

            swal({
                title: data.mensaje,
                type: 'error',
                confirmButtonText: 'Cerrar',
                confirmButtonColor: '#6b1180'
            }).then((result) => {

                if (result.value) {

                    $(".nombreProveedor").val("");
                    $(".nombreProveedor").focus();

                }

            })

        }

    })
    .catch(err => window.location = "/") //este es la solución

}
```